# How to inverse boolean in Vimscript?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I have the following script but not working:

1. I don't know what's the standard way to inverse the boolean(I used number `1/0`).
2. I not sure whether it's correct to put global variable, which I used to store plugin state, in `.vimrc` is a bad idea.
3. Why the error?

---

```
function! s:update_state() abort
    let old_mini = g:minimap_is_opened
    let old_fern = g:fern_is_opened
    g:minimap_is_opened == 0? g:minimap_is_opened = 1 : g:minimap_is_opened = 0
    g:fern_is_opened == 0? g:fern_is_opened = 1 : g:fern_is_opened = 0
    if old_mini==1 && old_fern==0
        return ":MinimapToggle\<CR>:Fern . -drawer -width=36 -toggle -reveal=%\<CR>"
    elseif old_fern==1 && old_mini==0
        return "\<CR>:Fern . -drawer -width=36 -toggle -reveal=%\<CR>:MinimapToggle"
    endif
endfunction
```

Usage:

```
nnoremap <silent><nowait><expr> <Tab> <SID>update_state()
```

But I got error:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>2_update_state:
line    3:
E492: Not an editor command: minimap_is_opened = 1 : g:minimap_is_opened = 0
```

Comment: You are using the ternary ? : operator in the wrong context. You need to do it this way:
`let g:minimap_is_opened = g:minimap_is_opened == 0 ? 1 : 0` -- Of course, it's much easier just to do: `let g:minimap_is_opened = !g:minimap_is_opened`

Answer (score 8):

You can invert a boolean with `!`:

```
let foo = 1
echo foo " will print 1
let foo = !foo
echo foo " will print 0
```

I'm afraid I can't help much with the overall function as I am unfamiliar with minimap, but that might help you get started.  Note that the syntax in your ternary operatory is incorrect.  If you are doing it that way you want:

```
let foo = foo == 0 ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: Can your last line simplified to `let foo = !foo ? 1 : 0`? I mean: is that every non-zero number treated as a true?

Comment: @job_start Yes, or `let foo = foo ? 0 : 1`.  You might find it helpful to read [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) if you haven't already, particularly [Chapter 21](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/21.html) which deals with "truthiness" and conditional statements.

Comment: worth pointing out here that in "classic" vim script uses numbers 1 and 0 for true and false.  So the result of ! is always 1 or 0.